# Is there a way to generate an empty Html node in Elm-Html?

Tags: elm

I'm writing a function that displays error messages, so in my view, I have something like

```
div [] [ displayErrors model ]
```

in the event that there are no errors, how can I make displayErrors return something that is interpreted as an empty Html node?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@robertjlooby's answer looks perfectly fine to me.

However, if you really want not to have any node, you could make `displayErrors` return a `Maybe (Html msg)`.

Then, you can change your code to the following:

```
import Maybe.Extra exposing (maybeToList)

div [] ( displayErrors model |> maybeToList )
```

When `displayErrors` returns `Nothing`, the `div` will be really empty.

Note: you can install the Maybe.Extra module with the following command:

```
elm package install elm-community/maybe-extra
```

Comment: Yeah, this is a nice solution. The only problem is, if I'm using this in a list. So for example: div [] [ stuff, (displayErrors model |> maybeToList) ], this wouldn't really work. I guess there is no really good way to address this with the existing Html function signatures. Maybe the return signature should be Maybe (Html Msg) instead of Html Msg.

Comment: In that case you can concatenate lists: `div [] ([stuff] ++ (displayErrors model |> maybeToList))`

Answer (score 30):

You can use an [`Html.text`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/latest/Html#text) node with an empty string:

```
emptyNode = Html.text ""
```

Comment: Does this get optimized away? I'm concerned about using these phantom nodes because of the possibility of triggering some CSS rule that leads to unintended results.

Comment: @jz87 looks like nothing gets rendered